# Gumstix Overo SSD1306 OLED

Tags: qt5, yocto, i2c, gumstix

Hello everybody,
I have been working for some time on the implementation of tools for coding an application in Qt5 on a Gumstix Overo platform with a Yocto Rocko kernel.
After some effort I managed to set up the development tools:
- Create a bootable SD card with Yocto Rocko and Qt5.
- Get cross-compilation tools to code Qt5 linux support on Gumstix Overo (ARM).
- Configure QtCreator to develop code and compile it for the Gumstix Overo.
All my research work with explanatory "step by step" are available on this [link](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixovero/src).

In order to use the I2C part of the Gumstix Overo, I would like to exploit the small OLED SSD1306 display.
I found a project that did it for a Beagle Bone [here](http://deeplyembedded.org/ssd1306-oled-driver-beaglebone/).
And the library practically ready to use [here](https://github.com/deeplyembeddedWP/SSD1306-OLED-display-driver-for-BeagleBone).

After adapting the project for the Gumstix Overo and compiling the code, I can start the application.
The problem is that after a short time running the program stops and show me these two [errors](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixovero/src/master/Dev/SSD1306/QT5_SSD1306_Error.png).
- ioctl error: Remote I/O error. 
- Chunk writtent to RAM -Failed. 
The display of the first error comes from an additionnal part that I have added in the code in line 202 [there](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixovero/src/master/Dev/SSD1306/qOLED/I2C.c).
The display of the second error comes from the library in the line 777 [there](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixovero/src/master/Dev/SSD1306/qOLED/SSD1306_OLED.c).

My unsuccessful searches on the internet make me to ask you for help.

Small precise, given the I2C communication voltage levels between the Gumstix Overo and the SSD1306 OLED display, an electronic adaptation has be made.

[the electrical assembly](http://forums-futura-sciences.digidip.net/visit?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Ffalcon1990%2Fgumstixovero%2Fsrc%2Fmaster%2FDev%2FSSD1306%2FElectronicAssembly.jpg&ppref=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.futura-sciences.com%2Fnewthread.php%3Fdo%3Dpostthread%26f%3D35&currurl=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.futura-sciences.com%2Flogiciel-software-open-source%2F823396-gumstix-overo-ssd1306-oled.html%23post6166955)
[I2C waveform](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixovero/src/master/Dev/SSD1306/I2C_WaveForm.BMP)
[Voltage level adaptation schematic](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixovero/src/master/Dev/SSD1306/BidirectionalI2cConvertor.png)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution. 
The problem was the logical level converter that not working for 1.8 VDC. 
I choose the PCA9306 Breakout from sparkfun [there](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11955) and it's working well. 
I hope that will help someone.